# Sort oberservableArray by multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, knockout.js

I am trying to sort by two items of an `obervableArray`. I have created a simplified version of this at http://jsfiddle.net/organa7/yyy3y2ka/.

```html
Line Group Id
<select data-bind="options: lineGroupIds, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'text', value: selectedGroupId">
</select>

Line Type
<select data-bind="options: lineTypes, optionsValue: 'value', optionsText: 'text', value: selectedLineType">
</select>

<button data-bind="click: addLine">Add Line</button>
</br>
Line Count:&nbsp;<span data-bind="text: lines().length"></span>
</br>
<table> 
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Line Group Id</th>
             <th>Line Type</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
<tbody data-bind='foreach: linesSorted'>
    <tr>
         <td>
            <span data-bind="text: lineGroupId"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: lineType"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

```javascript
function myViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedLineType = ko.observable(2);
    self.selectedGroupId = ko.observable(2);

    self.lines = ko.observableArray([
        {lineType: 1, lineGroupId: 1}, 
        {lineType: 1, lineGroupId: 2}, 
        {lineType: 1, lineGroupId: 3},

        /*{lineType: 2, lineGroupId: 1}, 
        {lineType: 3, lineGroupId: 1}, 
        {lineType: 2, lineGroupId: 1}, 
        {lineType: 2, lineGroupId: 2}, 
        {lineType: 3, lineGroupId: 2}, 
        {lineType: 2, lineGroupId: 1},*/
    ]);

    self.linesSorted = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return self.lines().sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.lineType == b.lineType ?
            0 :
            (a.lineType < b.lineType ? -1 : 1);
        }).sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.lineGroupId == b.lineGroupId ?
            0 :
            (a.lineGroupId < b.lineGroupId ? -1 : 1);
        })
    });    

    self.lineTypes = ko.observableArray([
        {value: 2, text: "2"},
        {value: 3, text: "3"}
    ]);

    self.lineGroupIds = ko.observableArray([
        {value: 1, text: "1"},
        {value: 2, text: "2"},
        {value: 3, text: "3"}
    ]);

    self.addLine = function () {
        self.lines.push({
            lineType: self.selectedLineType(),
            lineGroupId: self.selectedGroupId()
        });
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

They should be sorted by `LineGroupId` and then by `LineType`. For each `LineGroupId` there should be one and only one of `LineType` 1. This is the parent item. I have added a multiple sort to the lines that are bound to the table. It works fine until the number of lines goes over 10: then you get a lineType of 2 or 3 above lineType of 1. Any help on what is going on here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're sorting not the way you want to.

- **What you seem to want**: sort by Line Type first, ***then by*** Line Group Id.
- **What you are in fact doing**: sort by Line Type, then *sort the result **again*** by Line Group Id.

Here's an updated version of your sorting function:

```
self.linesSorted = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    return self.lines().sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.lineGroupId > b.lineGroupId) { return 1; }
        if (a.lineGroupId < b.lineGroupId) { return -1; }
        if (a.lineType > b.lineType) { return 1; }
        if (a.lineType < b.lineType) { return -1; }
        return 0;
    })
});
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yyy3y2ka/1/) for a demo.

PS. I recommend writing unit tests for this kind of logic. See for example [my somewhat related question about elegant "ThenBy" sorting in JavaScript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/70314/10034) on CodeReview.SE.

Comment: Thanks You.  This worked perfectly.  I had been searching for examples on how to do this for days and had found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like they're sorting textually instead of numerically. Use a numeric comparison function (see parameter example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)). Also, to sort by two fields, don't sort twice, do both comparisons in the same compare function. This ought to get you sorted (sorry):

```
function compareNumeric (a, b){return a-b}

self.linesSorted = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    return self.lines().sort(function (a, b) {
        return compareNumeric(a.lineType, b.lineType) ||  compareNumeric(a.lineGroupId, b.lineGroupId);
    })
});
```